# Is this predicate logic true?

Tags: predicate-logic

∃ x ∈ R, ∀ y ∈ R x ≥ y

Write the statement in English. A complete answer will not
use any mathematical notation, nor the symbols x and y.
Write down the truth value of the statement.
Write down the negation of the statement in symbols and in English.

my soln:

some real numbers are greater or equal to all real numbers.
false
noreal numbers are greater or equal to all real numbers

Pls help

Comment: Your version is fine. More idiomatic, in English, would be something like "There is a largest real number."

Comment: You are almost correct, although I would say "some real number is greater or equal to all real numbers." Or more precisely, "there is/exists a real number..."

Comment: The statement translates as: **There exists some other real number for all real numbers such that the first is greater than or equal to the latter**

The statement is false.

Comment: what about the negation? is mine ok?

Comment: Might as well write the formal negation as well and then see if your sentence corresponds to it. The negation is, $\neg(\exists x\in\mathbb R, \forall y\in \mathbb R, x\geq y)$. Recall that $\neg(\exists x,\phi(x))=\forall x,(\neg\phi(x))$ and $\neg(\forall x,\phi(x))=\exists x,(\neg \phi(x)$. Then the above negation becomes $\forall x\in \mathbb R, \exists y\in\mathbb R, x< y$. Is it true that if someone hands you a real number, you can give a real number greater than it?

Comment: I think the above statement is false  but if it were because ∃ x ∈ R, ∃ y ∈ R x ≥ y then it would be true for at least one integer x and another integer y...? Say x is 2 and y is 3 so 2 >= 3

Answer (score 1):

There exists a real number $x$, such that, for every real number $y$, $x$ is either greater than $y$ or equal to $y$. In other words, there is a real number which is greater than or equal to all real numbers.

This statement is false of course.

Proof by contradiction:

- Assume that there is such number $x$.
- Observe the number $y=x+1$.
- Obviously, $x$ is neither greater than $y$ nor equal to $y$.

Answer (score 0):

> $\exists(x \in \mathbb{R})[\forall (y \in \mathbb{R} ) [x \geq y]]$

It means:

> There exists a number in reals for which all real numbers are smaller or equal to it.

It's $\infty$, of course.

Comment: $\infty$ is not a real number. Saying "It's $\infty$" is not accurate.